# How to receive font loading event in react?

Tags: reactjs, fonts, loading, react-state

I am using react.
When using a font file in src in React, how can I change the state by receiving an event when the font is loaded?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in the first place? Normally, you just use web-safe fonts as fallback and swap to your fonts automatically once it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Font Face Observer](https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) library to load and wait for a font to load. Which you can do as follow:

```
var font = new FontFaceObserver('My Family');

font.load().then(
  () => console.log('Font is available'),
  () => console.log('Font is not available')
);
```